# Can't connect to certain WIFI-networks on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager

In just the last few weeks I've been having huge problems with connecting to certain WIFI-networks on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I can connect to my home WIFI and certain other ones (as well as my phone's hotspot) but some other networks (including work) I never seem to be able to connect to. When I choose them from the list of available networks, the computer just tries to connect with it for 10-20 seconds and then says it was disconnected.

I asked Google for help with this but none of the solutions I tried (restarting Network manager and so on) worked, I still get the same error. This is my wireless-info file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-UyzfVp6kcPLW9VcHBJMmtKWms/view?usp=sharing

This is quickly becoming a huge issue for me as I need to be online in order to do my work.

How do I fix this? Thanks a lot for all help!

//Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest that you remove the incorrect Broadcom driver. As your device is an Intel, the driver is not helpful. From the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r wl
```

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Is there any improvement? It may take a reboot.

Comment: I went through your amazing answer but it still doesn't work :(

When I try the first modeprobe-command, this is the answer I get:

modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.

When I get my country code I get 00, but when I try to change it, on both methods, I still get 00 as the country?

Also, I can't edit the IPv6 settings as they are all greyed out when I try to edit my work wifi (which I have never been able to connect to).

Also, your last few commands didn't make anything different, not that I noticed?

Anyway, thanks for your help, but how do I continue from here on out?

Comment: I managed to connect to my work WI-FI by removing it from my known networks and then re-adding it as a hidden network by typing in the name and password directly in the network manager. It's not fancy, but until I figure out why I can't connect properly, this is a good enough work around.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem after installing some software by using terminal. I can use  certain wifi for example:ENSAI-INVITES, but not ENSAI-ELEVES. The solution is:
Just try to remove this wifi in your networks list, and then add it as a hidden network by typing username and password.